# How to re-own my posts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I came across some posts on [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com) which seem to be migrated from the previously closed [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) site. I saw my name under the post but it was grayed out. For example:

- [Leaving wi-fi on all the time](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/leaving-wi-fi-on-all-the-time)

How can I re-own my posts?

Comment: Hmm that's a good one, because you can't add your ID yourself anymore :\

Comment: @Ivo: So, I'll sigh whenever I see my pale ancient ID...

Comment: Perhaps you're luckily and they'll reassociate it. Interestingly enough I do have some questions associated. Perhaps you can try reassociating all accounts, just to see if it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag any such posts for moderator attention asking for them to be re-associated. Mods can't fix it but devs can.

See also: [Migrated questions to Android. Will they be linked to my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64847/migrated-questions-to-android-will-they-be-linked-to-my-account)